# Play Local Music file in Music Player - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

> How to play local storage music file in flutter?
>   What is the dependency for it?

Comment: Have you tried with a Google Search? There are a ton of results for it, from Medium articles to Github projects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Github link I am attaching where you can find a music player with source code. in this code, there is a complete music player code where you can play, pause, next, previous, etc song

Here is the link https://github.com/iampawan/Flutter-Music-Player

Hope this answer will helpful for you :)